# TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." using JavaScript fetch

Tags: reactjs, postman, typeerror, fetch-api

I can make successful API-calls using **POSTMAN**. But when the call the same API with same config from my **react-app** it gives the error -

> TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

Code snippets as follows:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", API_TOKEN);
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
   
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: data,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    await fetch(API_URL, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Is it possibly a cors error?

Comment: I think if its a CORS error then it will be log on the console.

Comment: Okay. Then are you sure that the `API_URL` variable is valid. If it's an environment variable, from the `.env` file, I think it should be prefixed with `REACT_APP_`.

Comment: Actually API_URL is not from .env file. I replaced the exact url with API_URL at the time of posting.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use useEffect hook for POST requests